# How to store files in custom location

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I need to upload a file in my Laravel eCommerce app and store it inside the respective user's folder. My code looks like this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('attach')) {
            try {
                $file = $request->file('attach');
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

                Storage::disk('local')->put($filename,  File::get($file));
                Storage::move('app/'.$filename, 'app/public/uploads/'.$user_id.'/attach/'.$filename);
```

I've this in `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

But I get error while uploading a file:

> (1/1) FileNotFoundException: File not found at path: app/Test1.docx

How can I store/save a file in a custom location such as user's folder? The custom location where uploaded files are stored look like this: 
`'app/public/uploads/'.$user_id.'/attach/'`

Comment: only `Storage::disk('local')->put('app/public/uploads/'.$user_id.'/attach/'.$filename,  File::get($file));` should do the work, you don't need to move again

Comment: or if you want to keep your code as it is then change this to `Storage::disk('local')->put('app/'.$filename,  File::get($file));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by @sohel0415, here is the updated code that worked for me:

```
if ($request->hasFile('attach')) {
                    try {
                        $file = $request->file('attach');
                        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                        Storage::disk('local')->put('public/uploads/'.$user_id.'/attach/'.$filename, File::get($file));
```